# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

The Workplace's [fourth moderator election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Lilienthal]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6738938668515328/0).

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this because I don't see an answerable question here.

Comment: the results summary link has HTTPS problems of some sort.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words everyone! And of course thank you to everyone who participated in this election, particularly Christopher and Rory.

Comment: I know this might be posted by a bot (on behalf of the CMs), but: "and the new moderator**s** *is*"?

Comment: @muru: I have a template that's suited for multiple moderators. Looks like I didn't proofread my modifications very well this time. (And maybe I ought to just break down and save a copy of the single-moderator template. I've been hoping to get this automated.)-:

Comment: @JoeStrazzere thanks for the fix.  (Editing on a phone is challenging; was hoping somebody would make the fix.)

Answer (score 15):

Congratulations Lilienthal! Much deserved!

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations Lilienthal, and well done everyone!!  All the candidates were of a high quality and any one of them would have made an excellent addition to the moderator team.  Lilienthal is a trusted and effective member of the community, and I feel he will be a great asset to the community in his new role of Workplace Moderator.

Congratulations again, and welcome to the Moderator team! :)

Comment: I seem to believe Lilienthal is a woman. Not sure though, he/she has never stated it explicitly.

Comment: No doubt Lilienthal can clarify, if they so wish :)

Comment: @MaskedMan I have indeed avoided specifying so far but since you ask, "he" is correct. :)

Comment: @Lilienthal Thanks, the question that vexed humanity has finally been resolved. :)

Answer (score 9):

Congrats! Well done, Lilienthal!

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations, Lilienthal. You have made The Workplace a much better place already, and I am sure you will continue to contribute even more with the well-deserved diamond.

Answer (score 6):

Congrats. Best of luck with your new responsibilities and awesome powers.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, good to see someone rewarded for solid work.

Answer (score 2):

(Obligatory Congratulations Comment)